# OpenCv : How to detect color alterations in before/after picture of a painting?

Tags: c#, opencv, colors, emgucv

I’m coding an app to check if a painting has been damaged using two high resolution pictures taken before and after it’s shipping.

I have already managed to detect physical alterations (scratches, holes,…).

I know need to check if there is any color alterations: has the painting colors been globally or locally altered. Is there a way to detect such colors changes between the before and after pictures with opencv ?

My app is coded in c# so any answer using emgu.cv would be great but if you only know the answer in python it will be ok too.

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-detect-color-alterations-in-before-after-picture-of-a-painting/14359